# Kafka - timestamp order

Tags: apache-kafka

Assume I'm using `log.message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime`.

Also assume number of messages per topic/partition during first read:

- `topic0:partition0`: 5
- `topic0:partition1`: 0
- `topic0:partition2`: 3
- `topic1:partition0`: 2
- `topic1:partition1`: 0
- `topic1:partition2`: 4

and during second read:

- `topic0:partition0`: 5
- `topic0:partition1`: 2
- `topic0:partition2`: 3
- `topic1:partition0`: 2
- `topic1:partition1`: 4
- `topic1:partition2`: 4

If I read *first* message from each partition, does Kafka guarantee that reading again from each partition won't return a message that's older than those I read during first read?

Focus on `topic0:partition1` and `topic1:partition1` which didn't have any messages during first read, but have during second read.

Comment: yes, it does guarantee it, as far as the consumer group stays the same

Comment: @aran tnx! write as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: tried to explain a little bit more, hope it helps mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka guarantees message ordering at **partition level**, so your use case perfectly fits kafka's architecture.

There are some concepts to explain in here. First of all, you have the starting consumer position (when you first launch a new consumer group), defined by the **`auto.offset.reset`** parameter.

This will kick in **only if there's no saved offset** for that group, **or if a saved offset is not valid anymore** (f.e, if it was already deleted by retention policies). You should normally only worry for this if you launch a new consumer group (and you want to decide wether it starts from the oldest messages, or from the *present* - newest one).

Regarding your example, in normal conditions (there are no consumer shutdowns, etc), you have nothing to worry about. *`Consumers`* within a same *`consumer group`* will only read their messages once, no matter the number of partitions nor the number of consumers. These consumers remember their last read offset, and periodically save it in the **`_consumer_offsets`** topic.

There are 2 properties that define this periodical recording:

- **enable.auto.commit**
  Setting it to **`true`** (which is the default value) will allow the automatic commit to the `_consumer_offsets` topic.
- **auto.commit.interval.ms**
  Defines when the offsets are commited. For example, with a value of `10000`, your consumer offsets will be stored every 10 seconds.

You can also set enable.auto.commit to false and store your offsets in your own way (f.e to a database, etc), but this is a more special use case.

The auto offset committing will allow you to stop your consumers, and start them again later without losing any message nor reprocessing already processed ones (it's like a mark in a book's page). If you don't stop your consumers (and without any errors from broker/zookeeper/consumers), even less worries for you.

For more info, you can take a look here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#concepts

Hope it helps!